# Authorize.net SIM integration Relay URL not Working

Tags: php, authorize.net

PHP Authorize.net SIM relay url not working.

Is there a way to implement the realy url SIM integration?

We need to implement the secure payment without https SSL by direct the user to the authorize.net site and automatically come back to our site after payment using relay url.

I googled a lot but not get any answer,

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a variety of reasons for this. I suggest reading Authorize.Net's blog post called [Relay Response Basics and Troubleshooting](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I am working in test environment from localhost. Is that will be the problem?

Comment: Almost certainly it will. Unless you have set up your home network to allow your webserver to be publicly accessible Authorize.Net can't get to your relay response page.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response.